# Modificador de tipo: register

Tags: c, declaração-de-variável

O modificador de tipos `register` instrui o compilador a armazenar a variável direto nos registradores, entretanto não vejo muito o uso dela em códigos, isto posto, me surgem as seguintes dúvidas:

Em que contexto é recomendado seu uso e quando não usá-la?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Essencialmente ele não é mais necessário. Os compiladores são capazes de decidir quando colocar no registrador melhor que o programador. Seu uso pode até prevenir algumas otimizações que podem trazer melhor benefício. De fato a maioria dos compiladores a ignoram, se não totalmente, pelo menos na maioria das vezes, a não ser que as otimizações estejam desligadas, aí pode ser útil, mas porque faria isto?