# Qual o ganho da performance quando eu coloco register em minha variável?

Tags: c

Estou ainda lendo a apostila C Completo e Total, e diz que:

> [...] Isso significa que operações nas variáveis register poderiam ocorrer muito mais rapidamente que nas variáveis armezanadas na memória, pois o valor dessas variáveis era realmente conservado na CPU e não era necessário acesso à memória para determinar ou modificar seus valores [...]

Aqui ele não diz o ganho da performance que eu tenho, possui algum gráfico ou conteúdo explicativo? E quando devo usar realmente isso? Sei que não devo abusar, e nem arrays devem entrar como diz (Página 47):

> [...] Objetos maiores, como matrizes, obviamente não podem ser
>   armazenados em um registrador [...]

Edit1: Estou gostando bastante de `C`, estou vendo que deveria ter aprendido primeiro pois é fundamental ver como a memória funciona e etc... Uma outra dúvida, como `C` seria tipo "Pai" das outras linguagens, esse especificador de armazenamento também funciona em outras linguagens como `PHP`, `Python`, `JavaScript`, `Java`?

Edit2: Visualizei nos comentários e disseram que essa apostila é ruim e antiga, alguma sugestão para leitura?

Me pareceu que faltou informação para se completar...

Comment: Esse livro é muito antigo e não é completamente válido para os dias de hoje. Hoje em dia essa keyword não é mais tão útil. Compiladores modernos fazem isto automaticamente e também são melhores que nós, humanos, em escolher isto. Referência: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/578202/register-keyword-in-c

Comment: Esse livro é muito ruim, sério mesmo.

Comment: Vish! Sério? Qual livro me indicam? E por que é tão ruim assim?

Comment: Parabéns pela sua percepção, se souber levar bem tem potencial de se tornar um grande programador porque pelo menos enxerga algo diferente e que poucas pessoas enxergam, inclusive consegue mudar de ideia quando vê algo pela frente, em geral hoje em dia as pessoas são bastante teimosas. Eu acho que essa pergunta já foi respondida em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/169857/101. É isso, ele não é necessário há muito tempo, assim como outras linguagens também não precisa ou sequer faz sentido. Este é não só um livro antigo, é talvez o pior já escrito sobre C. Veja a [tag:c].

Comment: Isso não é uma apostila é pirataria de livro.

Answer (score 3):

A palavra `register` *sugere* ao compilador que essa variável deve ser alocada em um registrador. Isso era útil em compiladores antigos, em uma época que os algoritmos de alocação de registradores eram primitivos e as máquinas tinham pouca capacidade de processamento, o que tornava esse processo muito lento uma vez que o caso geral desse problema é NP-completo.

Hoje, a alocação de registradores é feita de maneira quase ótima pelos compiladores, o que torna o uso do `register` muito desnecessário, até desaconselhado. O compilador sabe, por meio de uma análise chamada *Liveness Analysis*, onde uma variável começa a existir, e onde ela não é mais necessária. Com isso ele consegue alocar e desalocar o registrador conforme o necessário.

Uma coisa que talvez seja útil do atributo `register` é que não é possível retirar o endereço dela, mas até hoje eu nunca vi ela ser usada para isso.

Comment: Vale lembrar que não é possível obter o endereço de uma variável `register`

Answer (score 2):

Em termos mais práticos, considere o simples exemplo abaixo:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int testecomregister() {
    register int x = 5;
    x = x + 2;
    x = x - 1;
    return x;
}

int testesemregister() {
    int x = 5;
    x = x + 2;
    x = x - 1;
    return x;
}

int main (void) {
    testecomregister();
    testesemregister();
    return 0;
}
```

Tomando as devidas proporções no momento de compilação para extrair as informações de depuração, façamos:

```
gcc -O0 -ggdb3 teste.c -o teste
```

Para verificar o assembly emitido de ambas as funções, extraimo-nas com o objdump e sed para filtrar a saída:

```
objdump -d teste -M intel | sed '/<testecomregister>:/,/^$/!d'

0000000000401106 <testecomregister>:
  401106:   55                      push   rbp
  401107:   48 89 e5                mov    rbp,rsp
  40110a:   53                      push   rbx
  40110b:   bb 05 00 00 00          mov    ebx,0x5
  401110:   83 c3 02                add    ebx,0x2
  401113:   83 eb 01                sub    ebx,0x1
  401116:   89 d8                   mov    eax,ebx
  401118:   5b                      pop    rbx
  401119:   5d                      pop    rbp
  40111a:   c3                      ret 


objdump -d teste -M intel | sed '/<testesemregister>:/,/^$/!d'

000000000040111b <testesemregister>:
  40111b:   55                      push   rbp
  40111c:   48 89 e5                mov    rbp,rsp
  40111f:   c7 45 fc 05 00 00 00    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],0x5
  401126:   83 45 fc 02             add    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],0x2
  40112a:   83 6d fc 01             sub    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],0x1
  40112e:   8b 45 fc                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4]
  401131:   5d                      pop    rbp
  401132:   c3                      ret
```

A diferença mais visível é que no caso utilizando register, as operações são feitas diretamente em rbx, enquanto no caso outro caso, as operações são feitas com base no registrador de base-offset. Para efeitos práticos, isso é negligível nos dias de hoje. Lembrando que a situação acima é forçada, quando eu coloco um nível de otimização, o gcc já faz o trabalho de casa me trazendo o resultado diretamente:

```
  401106:   b8 06 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x6
  40110b:   c3                      ret
```

Em outras palavras, o compilador sabe o que faz. Deixe-o trabalhar :)

Comment: É possível fazer o GCC remover até as chamadas de função se estas forem declaradas como static, ou se o _Link Time Optimization_ for habilitado através da flag `-flto`.

Comment: Bem, se eu forçar um inline iria ficar menos didático pra resposta hehehe No caso de um mero printf, a parte de interesse iria ficar reduzida a um mero mov esi <valordireto>; mov edi <lugar da plt>

Comment: Ao declarar como `static` você não está forçando ela ser `inline`. Você apenas diz ao compilador que esta função não sera visível para para o contexto externo, ou seja, o escopo dela é apenas esse arquivo. Isso permite que o GCC quebre os padrões de chamada de função e faça otimizações ainda mais agressivas. Transformá-la em `inline` é apenas uma das coisas que ele pode fazer.

Mas de fato, fica um pouco menos didático :-)

Comment: Ah, perdão. Eu não prestei atenção no "static", pois não estava destacado no comentário. Sim, você tem razão.